# How to insert large string in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, database, string

I'm trying to insert a large string into a `nvarchar(max)` column, but after inserting I found, that string was cut. There was only 43601 characters stored.

What is wrong?

Comment: Can you show us what you've done so far?

Comment: **HOW** do you insert those strings? And how to do tell it's truncated?? What length do you get when checking the actual string length, e.g. `SELECT LEN(columnname) FROM dbo.YourTable;` - is it *really* truncated, or is just the display in the GUI limited?

Comment: The real length (SELECT LEN) was 102 275 symbols.  But How i can see  full string ? i'm using sql management studio

Comment: You can cast it to xml to see the full string. Try something like this:

select @variable_with_long_text
 as [processing-instruction(x)] FOR XML PATH

The processing-instruction bit is there to stop it from showing characters such as < to &lt;

Answer (score 0):

It stores complete string but when you use select statement SQL interface display only certain number of characters...you can try reading thru .NET/java or try getting data thru SubString().. you should see complete data...

Answer (score 0):

Usually you'll take warning text like 'string or binary will be truncated' in a case of truncation during insert. If you didn't have such warning, then likely You've inserted data successfully.

To check it, you can cast your field with large data to XML type and then open it to ensure what it's been stored well.

Example:

```
SELECT TOP 1000 [id]
      ,CAST([text] AS XML)
  FROM [AnomalyDetection].[dbo].[TableA]
```

Result:

[image]

And finally, click on data to open it in the editor